# Memory address of array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

Please help me out. I'm totally confused about in this memory address.

```
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];

    NSLog(@"Address of array =  %p",&arr);
    NSLog(@"Array's element Address =  %p",arr);
    NSLog(@"Address 0th element %p",[arr objectAtIndex:0]);

    NSLog(@"Address of array =%lx",(long)&arr);
    NSLog(@"Array's element Address =  %lx",(long)arr);
    NSLog(@"Address 0th element %lx",(long)[arr objectAtIndex:0]);

    **Output**

    Address of array =  0xbfffd804
    Array's element Address =  0x866f340
    Address 0th element 0x4748
    Address of array =bfffd804
    Array's element Address =  866f340
    Address 0th element 4748
```

I'm getting this output but i'm confused with second and third output because according to my knowldge second and third output should be same. So please any one can explain me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this was a plain C array you might be right, but your `arr` is an instance of a class, not the base address of whatever data structure NSMutableArray uses to store its objects (which is probably not a plain C array, either).

Comment: You mean arr have different address from 0th item. If it is intanstance variable. Right ?

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary: Yes, the address of an NSArray object is not the same as the address of the first item in the array, and in fact there is no relationship between the two.

Comment: @Chuck you means objective-c and 'c' language concept are different in this case. I think in 'c' language the address of an Array is the same as the address of the first item in the array.

Comment: Yes, a C array is a primitive data structure that stores its contents in contiguous memory addresses. An NSArray/NSMutableArray is an Objective-C class, which has some other internal data structure that stores the objects it contains, along with a bunch of other instance variables that allow it to function. The memory layout of these things is effectively arbitrary.